# How to group items that will have different text, and align them across the website evenly?

Tags: html, css

So basically I have 4 rectangles, they each have different text and will do different actions when clicking on them. I would like them spaced out evenly across the webpage, but keep that spacing when the window scales bigger or smaller. Also, how would I group these together so I can set default values and only have one block of code for everything.

```css
.shortStoryBox,
.novelBox,
.poetryBox,
.scriptBox {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #55d6aa;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 60vh;
}

.shortStoryBox {
  left: 5vw;
}

.novelBox {
  left: 53vw;
}

.poetryBox {
  right: 53vw;
}

.scriptBox {
  right: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<section class="categoryBox">

  <div class="shortStoryBox">
    <h1 style="color:#444; text-align:center; padding-top:15%;"> Short Stories </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="novelBox">
    <h1 style="color:#444; text-align:center; padding-top:15%;"> Novels </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="poetryBox">
    <h1 style="color:#444; text-align:center; padding-top:15%;"> Poems </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="scriptBox">
    <h1 style="color:#444; text-align:center; padding-top:15%;"> Scripts </h1>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: check this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and somewhere you will find `space-between` / `space-around` / `space-evenly`, etc

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do this, but here is how i usually do it:

```css
body{
    margin:0.5vw;
    padding:0.5vw;
}
.shortStoryBox, .novelBox, .poetryBox, .scriptBox {
    float: left;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #55d6aa;
    padding: 1vw; 
    margin: 1vw;
    width: 20.5vw;
    height: 150px;
    top: 60vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="categoryBox">

    <div class="shortStoryBox">
        <h1 style="color:#444; text-align:center; padding-top:15%;"> Short Stories </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="novelBox">
        <h1 style="color:#444; text-align:center; padding-top:15%;"> Novels </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="poetryBox">
        <h1 style="color:#444; text-align:center; padding-top:15%;"> Poems </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="scriptBox">
        <h1 style="color:#444; text-align:center; padding-top:15%;"> Scripts </h1>
    </div>

</section>
```

Note that in order to get the divs evenly align in the viewport using this method, body margin and padding must be half the divs margin and padding, and then you split what's left between the divs to determine their width.